# Error updating/installing new Anaconda packages on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I recently updated Anaconda to version 1.5.1. Here is some information on my install.

```
Current conda install:

             platform : osx-64
conda command version : 1.5.1
       root directory : /Applications/Anaconda
       default prefix : /Applications/Anaconda
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
environment locations : /Applications/Anaconda/envs
          config file : None
```

When I run `$ conda update conda` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Anaconda/bin/conda", line 5, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/Applications/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 121, in        main
args.func(args, p)
File "/Applications/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 36, in execute
conda = Anaconda()
File "/Applications/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/anaconda.py", line 43, in __init__
self._index = PackageIndex(fetch_index(self.channel_urls))
File "/Applications/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/package_index.py", line 42, in __init__
pkg = Package(pkg_info)
File "/Applications/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/package.py", line 58, in __init__
for spec_string in self._info['requires'])
KeyError: 'requires'
```

I've searched through GitHub and on here, and could not find a solution to the issue. Does anyone know how to fix this so I can install/update conda packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `conda update conda` again. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

For update Anaconda, Conda, and Anaconda Navigator use :

```
conda update --all
```

That's worked for me.